# Get-ChildItem only ever gets 170 items

Tags: powershell, powercli

When I run the below I only get 170 items. I updated my powershell version just in case. I believe there may be an issue with the get-childitem get slower as it processes more but it goes fairly quick and then stops completely. Is there a size limit that can be adjusted?

```
$datastore = Get-Datastore -name "mystore"
New-PSDrive -Location $datastore[0] -Name ds -PSProvider VimDatastore -Root “\”
set-location ds:\
Get-ChildItem -Include *.iso -name -recurse
```

....

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.15063.1155
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.15063.1155
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: What do you mean "stops completely" ... if the folder to "search" is slightly big it might be still running and looking for *ISO files!?

Comment: The command line will not be available to type again but I leave it for an hour and no more is presented to me. The first rows populate less than 1 per second then it's like it pauses. There is about 30 folders with varying amount of files in them, may be 20 each, so I would expect 600items returned. The size of each file is about 1GB but as I am using the -name switch not sure that counts.

Comment: I have no idea whether it'll help, but you can try `-Filter *.iso`: `-Filter` matches at the _source_  - if the provider supports it  - and is much faster than `-Include`.

Comment: Just to figure out what this behaviour causes you could try to use `robocopy /L` and exclude everything else like junction points for files and directories and all that stuff. Did you try to evaluate the result with the Explorer?

Comment: Just used explorer and found someone had put an offline installer for Visual Studio in there, which has many files and folders would the exclude command be able to avoid this?